# Java does not recognize \n when read from file

Tags: java, arrays, string, escaping

If I print directly as

```
System.out.println("a\nb");
```

the result will be as expected, with a new line between characters,
but if I read the same line from a text file using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines;
    lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filename.txt"));
    String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(array[0]);
```

the text displayed will be exactly as written in a file "a\nb" without a new line between the characters. toString and other methods do not help.

How should I update the code?

Comment: Does the file contain a newline or does it contain the characters `\n`?

Comment: it's a \n character

Comment: If it's the characters `\n` then it will show as the characters `\n`. If it's a newline, it will show as a newline.

Comment: Well, it works fine with json. And the file comprises several lines, each one of those containing several "new lines", so reading them by line is impossible.

Comment: Your info is confusing. You claim (1) *but if I read the same line from a text file* and (2) *it's a \n character*.  These cannot both be true.  (1) requires the  4characters a, backslash, n, b, else it is neither the same nor "a" line.  (2) requires3 characters:  a, newline, b.  In fact, this (3) *the text displayed will be exactly as written in a file "a\nb"* says that there is one line with 4 characters in the file, a, backslash, n, b.  And that is exactly what you get by reading the file.  If you want to convert backlash, n, to a newline, you will need to write code to do it.

Comment: Hi @LXA does `System.out.println("a");System.out.println("b");` give the result you expect?

Comment: Considering backlsash,n to represent a newline is something the Java compiler does when it is compiling your code. It does not follow that backslash,n anywhere else is considered to be a newline.

Comment: `Files.readAllLines()` will do this to ya. Try: `lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filename.txt")).stream().flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\\\n"))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the colleagues and commenters got an explanation and an answer (not the most elegant approach though).
"\n" in the code is interpreted as a new line character, but when read from a file it becomes a set of two characters: "\" and "n" and is no longer properly recognized. The shortest way to eliminate the problem would be to replace these characters with the new line in the code of the program, adding  "replace("\n", "\n")". So, the code becomes as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines;
    lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filename.txt"));
    String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(array[0].replace("\\n", "\n"));
```